# MS Word 2010: Numbered headings in header

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word document in which I use a multilevel list in my headings headings like so:

> Section 1: ___
>
> 1.1 __
>
> 1.2 __
>
> Section 2: __
>
> 2.1 __

My problem is that I have The first level headings (Section 1, Section 2 etc.) in the headers since that's the only way they will fit nicely and show on each page, and the second level headings don't seem to want to follow the numbering of those (ie. 2.1 above is instead shown as 1.3, or if I select Restart at 1, 1.1).

Is there a way to get around this where I can keep the headings in the headers or do I have no choice but to do a format overhaul?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tzwlf3kb1xd9zy/Aaaa.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating a new Multilevel list to match these requirements and with just a few tweaks it is working. Perhaps try applying the list again. I'm assuming you set up the second list level like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried this in a new document and it gave me the same problem. The fact that I add section breaks (new page) between each section so I can change the header might not help.

Otherwise the headings I have work fine when I use the first level title outside of the header. Each level is also linked to a style (Heading 1, Heading 2).

In addition, When I use Heading 1 outside of the headers, It gives me "Section 2" even if it is placed after where "Section 4" has been specified in the header. I'm just guessing that the headers obey their own, separate numbering within themselves?

Comment: @Help, Could you upload the document somewhere for testing? I can't seem to reproduce any issue on my side.

Comment: document has been uploaded and linked in original question. Thanks for your persistent help.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and the only way I found to make it disappear was to remove the ListGal.dat file as suggested by Simon Blom in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-numbered-headings/d56d8e2e-7205-497d-b36c-92b0b0d6f2d4.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline.